# Trying to create a list of lists by using a While Loop and appending a list that clears and updates with inputs. Doesn't work. How to fix?

Tags: python

Sorry ahead of time if my wording is basic, I'm a college student doing this for fun.

I'm trying to use a while loop to create a list of lists (LoL) by appending an "updating list" which clears, updates, and then appends again to the list of lists.

However, this will update the LoL and create a list that consists of the (updating list * how many times I have appended it).

This is what I mean:

```
fulllst = [] # List of Lists
temp = [] # Updating List


while True:
    temp.clear() 
    while True:
        item = input("Enter item: ")
        if item == "done": #Ends the updating list and sends it back to be cleared.
            fulllst.append(temp)
            print(fulllst)
            break
        else:
            temp.append(item)
            print(fulllst)
            continue
```

So my question is: What can I do to go around this? I need it so that I can append that same list multiple times with different values each time.

Thanks.

edit:
so, for example, I want to make 1 list of lists consisting of 3 lists with different values inside. It won't work with this code because since I appended the "updating list," whenever I clear it at the beginning of the loop, it clears the list inside the LoL. I tried to show this in this image:

[Image of attempting to make three different lists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hb86.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Areas to fix in your code:

1. temp = [] needs to be inside the main while loop.
2. You are not exiting from the main while loop. Your break statement only exits from the inner while loop

See my changes to address these:

If you want multiple list of lists, you need to go back into the loop. In this case, you are not exiting the main loop at all.

```
fulllst = [] # List of Lists
ans = 'y'
while ans.lower().startswith('y'):
    temp = [] # Updating List
    while True:
        item = input("Enter item: ")
        if item == "done": #Ends the updating list and sends it back to be cleared.
            fulllst.append(temp)
            break
        else:
            temp.append(item)
    ans = input ('do you want another list of list item [Y/N] : ')
print (fulllst)
```

The below will give you the following answer:

```
Enter item: apple
Enter item: banana
Enter item: done
do you want another list of list item [Y/N] : y
Enter item: cake
Enter item: sugar
Enter item: done
do you want another list of list item [Y/N] : n
[['apple', 'banana'], ['cake', 'sugar']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move temp to the inner while loop:

```
fulllst = [] # List of Lists

while True:
    temp = [] # Updating List
    while True:
        item = input("Enter item: ")
        if item == "done": #Ends the updating list and sends it back to be cleared.
            fulllst.append(temp)
            print(fulllst)
            break
        else:
            temp.append(item)
            print(fulllst)
            continue
```